# If URL contains string, then do something with substring

Tags: jquery

I want to write a jQuery function that reads the URL for a string like so and then does something with the substring after it. Something like this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/more/**ID_NUMBER**') > -1) {
    console.log('got more');
    console.log(this);
    console.log(**ID_NUMBER**);
}
```

But I'm not sure how to refer to `**ID_NUMBER**` without hardcoding it. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for regular expressions:

```
var id = /\/more\/(\d+)/.exec(location.href);
if (id)
```

Comment: _Man_, that was fast. Thanks!